# Mount cifs between two centos vms as user gives mount error(13): Permission denied

Tags: centos, permissions, mount, cifs, smb

I am trying to mount a folder from centos vm (ver 8) to another cent os vm (ver 7) but getting the following error. Can someone let me know what is going wrong here.

```
mount.cifs -vvv //server-ip//workspaces/folder /tmpMount -o username=user         
Password for user@//server-ip//workspaces/folder:  ************
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=server-ip,unc=\\server-ip\,user=user,prefixpath=workspaces/folder,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied

smb.conf output

[global]
        security = user
        server role = standalone
        client use spnego = no
        client ntlmv2 auth = no
        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

[workspaces]
        path = /workspace/path
        browseable = Yes
        writable = no
        guest ok = Yes
        read only = Yes
```

Following are the dmesg logs. I have disabled the firewall and selinux to make sure nothing is blocking the mount cifs. smb.service is running. Not sure what else to check.

```
Jan 28 15:01:26 localhost.localdomain notice kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Jan 28 15:01:26 localhost.localdomain err kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Jan 28 15:01:26 localhost.localdomain err kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13

[user@localhost ~]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Comment: Did you create a Samba user on the server?

Comment: The samba account should exist in smbpasswd and on the server.  I also ran into issues using special characters in the passwords as well.

Comment: @ajgringo619 - that was the issue, i thought i created it but actually i did not. creating the user solved it for me. Thanks.